# Find row number for specific change in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, row

I have a file like this:

```
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
B
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
C         
C        
C         
C        
C       
C
C            
C
C
B   
B   
B
B   
B
```

I like to print the row number where there is a change from C to B. Like here in row 9 and 27. I need to row number only. How to do that in numpy python.

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to write code, which you do not appear to have attempted to do yet.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Kinda solved it for him before I let him attempt anything, sorry...

Comment: `How to do that ..` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm really new in SO and in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution, but it's not using Numpy

```py
f = open('yourfile.txt', 'r')
x = 0
for i in f:
   x = x + 1
   if i == 'B':
      print('row' + str(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I only need those row numbers where 1st 'B' appear. Like row 9 and 27.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Do you want the code to stop when it comes to the first B?

Comment: I need a code where it only print those row number where it switched from 'C' to 'B'. In my input file there are two such events. In 1st case, at row 9 where row8='C' and row9='B'. In 2nd case, row26='C' and row27='B'. So, I like to find only those rows whose previous row is C and then it switches to 'B'

Comment: So if row8="C" and row9="B" you want to print row8 or row9?

Comment: I like to print row9

Answer (score 0):

If working in pure numpy (this is C-level), I advise you to use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) for comparison of neighbour items:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.loadtxt(r'your_file.txt', dtype='O')
marker_idx = np.flatnonzero((x[1:]=='B') & (x[:-1]=='C')) + 1 #default way
print(marker_idx + 1) #since you are counting from 1 for some reason
```

**Output**

```
[ 9 27]
```